# Can't access port 8080 on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

I just started a new AWS EC2 instance. In the instance's security group I added a new rule to open port 8080 as well as port 80.

I created a docker image and container that runs an apache server as per the aws [tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/docker-basics.html).

When I run `docker run -p 80:80 hello-world` (where hello-world is the apache container image), everything works fine and I can access the server from the public network (using a web browser, or a curl command).

However, when I run `docker run -p 8080:80 hello-world` and I try to send a GET request (web browser, or curl) I get a connection timeout.

If I login to the host that is running the docker container, the curl command works fine. This tells me that port 8080 isn't really open to the public network, and something is blocking it, what could that be?

Comment: Can you post eact image. so that i will try from my end. It has to work according to your explanation.

Comment: Thanks Jinna! The image is in the tutorial link. I didn't put it in so I don't complicate the post.

Comment: I have gone through the tutorial, what you have tried as to work perfectly.  What is your curl command after running app on port 8080? try with IP:8080

Comment: Yeah that's it, also I know it works since the result is "timeout while... on port 8080"

Comment: Could it be the machine that I'm using? I selected a specific instance (free tier) maybe there's a config to it that is blocking 8080. I checked iptables and there's nothing there, I also checked the firewall and it's disabled.

Comment: Only Inbound rule open TCP to anywahere. that has to work. nothing else. Or else try with new rule may be 8082

Answer (score 3):

I tried to reproduce the thing, and I wasn't able to do it (it worked for me), so things that you should check:

1) Check that security group has indeed opened ports 80 and 8080 to your ip (or 0.0.0.0/0 if this is just a test just to confirm that this is not a firewall issue).

2) check the container is running:

```
docker ps -a
```

you should see: 0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp under ports.

3) check that when you are sending the GET request, you are specifying the port 8080 in the request, so your browser should look something like:

```
http://your.ip:8080
```

or curl:

```
curl http://your.ip:8080
```

Answer (score 1):

warning: just for testing
For testing: Setting Security Groups can solve the problem.

SecurityGroups > Inbound > Edit inbound rules > Add new rules > All TCP

[image]

Comment: this should be used only for testing purposes, as it's terrible practice. here you are opening all ports, to all ips for this box. this is screaming for so many possible attack vectors

Comment: Yes, I agree with @SimonErnestoCardenasZarate.